# What are the various ways of doing this code?

Tags: ruby

Create a function that takes a number as an argument and returns a grade based on that number.

> Score Grade
>
> Anything greater than 1 or less than 0.6   'F'
>
> 0.9 or greater "A"
>
> 0.8 or greater "B"
>
> 0.7 or greater "C"
>
> 0.6 or greater "D"

I was trying to figure out another way to write this code because the interpreter won't accept it. Can someone assist me with this?

```
def grader(score)
  if score >= 0.9 
    return "A"
  elsif score >= 0.8 
    return "B"
  elsif score >= 0.7  
    return "C"
  elsif score >= 0.6  
    return "D"
  elsif score < 0.5 or score > 1.01 
    return "F"
  else
    return "O"
  end
end
```

Comment: How you get `score` ?

Comment: *the interpreter won't accept it*? What error did you get?

Comment: Oh the error is, "The value is not what was expected".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest to use case statement for that purpose:

```
def grader(score)
  case score
  when 0.9..1    then 'A'
  when 0.8...0.9 then 'B'
  when 0.7...0.8 then 'C'
  when 0.6...0.7 then 'D'
  else                'F'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hash` like config.

```
GRADE_TABLE = {(0.9..1) => 'A', (0.8..0.9) => 'B', (0.7..0.8) => 'C', (0.6..0.7) => 'D'}
def get_grade(score)
  GRADE_TABLE.each{|sc, grade| return grade if sc.include?(score)}
  'F'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRADES = [[0.9, "A"], [0.8, "B"], [0.7, "C"], [0.6, "D"], [-Float::INFINITY, "F"]]

def grader(score)
  score = 0 if score > 1
  GRADES.find { |k,_| score >= k }.last
end

grader 0.50  #=> "F" 
grader 0.60  #=> "D" 
grader 0.65  #=> "D" 
grader 0.70  #=> "C" 
grader 0.79  #=> "C" 
grader 0.82  #=> "B" 
grader 0.93  #=> "A" 
grader 1.07  #=> "F"
```